# Python: modify builtin print functionality

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, jython, stdin

I want to customize the `print` statement in Python for additional text. But with my approach, it seems that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is getting buffered in the input.

The program I used is:

```
class rename_print:
    def __init__(self, stdout):
        self.stdout = stdout     
    def write(self, text):
        self.stdout.write('###' + text)     
        self.stdout.flush()
    def close(self):
        self.stdout.close()

import sys

prints = rename_print(sys.stdout)
sys.stdout = prints
print 'abc'
```

The output I get is

> ###abc###

The output I expected is

> ###abc

What might be the reason of this? I doubt that input stream is getting buffered with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You never showed us the printing code, so we have no idea what the bug can be.

Comment: sorry for the miss..edited the code accordingly..

Comment: I think what is happening is that print implicitly adds a newline. This extra print is also calling your redirected write function so you get another "###\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that print implicitly adds a newline. This extra print is also calling your redirected write function so you get another "###\n"

It's a bit hacky, but try this:

...

```
def write(self, text):
    if text!="\n":
       self.stdout.write('###' + text)
```

...

Comment: thanks a lot guys.i was trying to remove  the '\n' from buffer .anyway this works..

Comment: this fails when there are two print statements.We have to handle that also.

Answer (score 2):

`print` writes a newline character to the output stream per default (or a space between each argument). so you get two calls to `write`, one with `"abc"` and one with `"\n"`.

so if you don't want that behaviour, you have to treat that calls separately.